# How to use startAt() in Firebase query?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Let's suppose above firebase database schema.

What I want to is retrieve messages which after "15039996197" timestamp. Each of message object has a `createdAt` property.

How can I get messages only after specific timestamp? In this case, last two messages are what I want to retrieve.

I tried `` firebaseb.database().ref(`/rooms/$roomKey/messages`).startAt('15039996197') `` but failed. It return 0. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The case with your query is that it's expecting that the `message` node should have a number value to start with, in that case you want a child node with the name `createdAt`. So in that case you must specify that you want to order by `createdAt`, thus you need to do this

```
firebase.database().ref(`/rooms/$roomKey/messages`).orderByChild('createdAt').startAt('15039996197').on(//code);
```

This way it'll return all nodes inside `message` that has a child named `createdAt` an it starts at `15039996197`. Ordering your query may be a little bad for performance, for that i sugest taking a look at .indexOn rule.

For more information take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderByChild).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The JSON shows that the timestamp is stored as a number, so `.startAt(15039996197)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi. Can I ask you something? Do you know which is proper data schema? `1. Use timestamp as a key like Rishabh's answer` vs `2. Use my previous data schema and query with .orderByChild and .startAt`

Comment: I am trying to use timestamp as a key, but the query failed. `fb.database().ref(/rooms/$roomKey/messages).startAt(timestam‌​p)`

Comment: There is no singular *proper* schema, it always depends on the use-cases of your app. But the fact that you don't get results with your current query is due to two problems in the code: 1) you need to call `orderBy("createdAt")` (as Gabriel shows in is answer) 2) you need to pass a number to `startAt()` since you store the timestamps (correctly) as numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Data Retrieval works node by node.
So whatever data you want to get, the entire node is traversed.
So in your case to get any message your complexity would be O(number of messages).

You would want to restructure the way you are storing the data and put createdAt in Node instead of Child.

Comment: As your recommend, I use timestamp as a key. but `fb.database().ref(`/rooms/$roomKey/messages`).startAt(timestamp)` won't work. any Idea ??

Answer (score 0):

If your database structure looks like that, you can use:

```js
firebase.database()
     .ref(`/rooms/$roomKey/messages`)
     .orderByChild('createdAt')
     .startAt('15039996197').on('value', snapshot => { /* your code here */ });
```

But if you work with a lot of data entries, you can also name the item key with the timestamp, instead of storing the timestamp in your data. This saves a little data on your database.

```js
firebase.database().ref(`${rooms}/${roomKey}/${timestamp}`).set("value");
```

To retrieve the data in that case instead of `orderByChild('createdAt')`, you'll use `orderByKey()`. Because firebase keys are of the string type, you need to make shure to parse the timestamp in the `.startAt()` to a string.

It will then look something like this:

```js
firebase.database()
     .ref(`/rooms/$roomKey/messages`)
     .orderByKey()
     .startAt(`${15039996197}`).on('value', snapshot => { /* your code here */ });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that:

```
firebase.database().ref('/rooms/$roomKey/messages')
                .orderByChild('createdAt')
                .startAt('150399')
                .endAt('1503999\uf8ff')
                .on('value', function (snapshot) {
                    var key = snapshot.key,
                    data = snapshot.val();
                    console.log(key + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data))
                });
```

Be sure to set endAt().

Comment: This would only get messages with that specific timestamp, not all the messages **after** that timestamp.