# I keep getting the error: Error: Too many arguments provided to Query.startAt(). when using AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have a simple function that accepts parameters and returns the dataset

```
search(searchValues , numOfItems, startKey?) {
    return this.db.collection('gppContract', ref => ref
    .where('financialYear', '==', searchValues.financialYear)
    .startAt(startKey)
    .orderBy('amount', 'desc')
    .limit(numOfItems + 1))
      .valueChanges();


  }
```

What am i doing wrong or missing? am at a loss here.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936014/how-to-use-startat-in-firebase-query. Have a look. It looks like you have to do the `orderBy` *before* the `startAt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `orderBy()` needs to be before `startAt()`, to know according to which node the result should be.

Second, `orderBy()` only takes one argument and it should be the same field as `where()`, from the docs:

> Range filter and orderBy should be on the same fields:
>
> `citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("population")`

Check this:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

Comment: orderBy also accept 'desc' see more https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data